# Как сделать перебор по индексу и добавление текста? Python

Tags: python, telegram

Всем привет. Учусь работать с питоном, пишу бота в телегу. Делаю бота и застрял на переборе клавиатуры, нужно чтобы цикл брал с каждым шагом следующий индекс и доблавял к callback_data нужную строку. Буду рад и просто подсказкам. Изначально написал в 4 строки одно и тоже руками и все работало, но понимаю что это не дело.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    url_help = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Помощь", url="https")
    c = choose = ["Asus", "HP","Acer"]
    for c in range(3):
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(choose[0], callback_data="test"))
    keyboard.add(url_help)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, сделай свой выбор", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
choose = ["Asus", "HP","Acer"]
for c in choose:
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(c, callback_data="test"))
```

Для нумерации callback data

```
choose = ["Asus", "HP","Acer"]
for num, c in enumerate(choose):
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(c, callback_data=f"test{num}"))
```

Comment: а как добавить к "test" что-то еще с каждым проходом?

Comment: Не обязательно чтобы добавлял что-то новое, если возможно чтобы данные из списка так-же не различались.

Comment: Что именно надо добавить к test?  Второй вопрос не понял.

Comment: Чтобы был test1 или test2 в некст проходах, мне нужно чтобы кнопки передавали инфу. Человек нажал кнопку и отправился запрос в БД, и обработал. Есть вариант это сделать не разделяя callback_data На разные?

Comment: @Широ 
for num, c in enumerate(choose):
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(c, callback_data=f"test{num}")). Добавил в ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое =)